# Prisma ORM relation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, prisma

Trying to figure out how to make this relation between two tables by doing a lookup on second table.

```
model Person {
  personId                 String                     @id @default(uuid())
  address                  String                     @unique
  displayName              String?                    @unique
  emailAddress             String
  allow                    Allow[]
}

model Allow {
  allowId    String   @id @default(uuid())
  address    String
  createdAt  DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt  DateTime @updatedAt
  profile    Profile  @relation(fields: [address], references: [address])

  @@unique([allowId, address])
}
```

I'm trying to return a Person object with a property of 'canAllow' which basically pulls back all the data for a Person with another property of 'canAllow' which gets set by checking if there is a matching address in the Allow table.

Comment: How does `Profile` model looks like? You also have `@@unique` on `creatorId` but there is such field in your code.

Comment: @Danila fixed, was scrubbing some of the data to generic terms.